# NodeJS - Express - getting response from Database

Tags: node.js, database, express

I made a route using NodeJS and Express and can connect to Database and retrieve data.

How to push the whole response into 1 JSON object (instead of printing as a console print):

```
app.get('/db', function(req, res){
  connection.execute({
    sqlText: sqlStatement,

    complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Number of rows: ' + rows.length);
          console.log('Rows:');
          for (row in rows) 
            console.log(JSON.stringify(rows, null, 2));
        }
    },
  });

  res.send({ name: 'done' });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that everything else is working correctly (where is `sqlStatement` defined?), what you want to do is to use res.json(), like:

```
app.get('/db', function(req, res) {
  connection.execute({
    sqlText: sqlStatement,

    complete: function(err, stmt, rows) {
        if (err) {
          var error = 'Failed to execute statement due to the following error: ' + err.message;
          console.error(error);
          return res.send(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Number of rows: ' + rows.length);
          console.log('Rows:');
          return res.json({data: rows, message: 'done'});
        }
    },
  });
});
```